# Modify gulp file to run customized browserify command

Tags: node.js, gulp, browserify, gulp-watch

I would like to use gulp to run a custom browserify command whenever a js file (`function.js`) is modified.

The browserify command that I want to run is;

```
$ browserify function.js --standalone function > bundle.js
```

I am using this gulpfile.js as sample.

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/fast-browserify-builds-with-watchify.md

How do I modify this gulpfile to run the customized browserify command?

```
'use strict';

var watchify = require('watchify');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var assign = require('lodash.assign');

// add custom browserify options here
var customOpts = {
  entries: ['./src/index.js'],
  debug: true
};
var opts = assign({}, watchify.args, customOpts);
var b = watchify(browserify(opts)); 

// add transformations here
// i.e. b.transform(coffeeify);

gulp.task('js', bundle); // so you can run `gulp js` to build the file
b.on('update', bundle); // on any dep update, runs the bundler
b.on('log', gutil.log); // output build logs to terminal

function bundle() {
  return b.bundle()
    // log errors if they happen
    .on('error', gutil.log.bind(gutil, 'Browserify Error'))
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    // optional, remove if you don't need to buffer file contents
    .pipe(buffer())
    // optional, remove if you dont want sourcemaps
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true})) // loads map from browserify file
       // Add transformation tasks to the pipeline here.
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./')) // writes .map file
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
}
```

I am using node.js v6.9 on webstorm.

Comment: The modification should be done in `customOpts`, though I'm not sure exactly how.

Answer (score 1):

The command you want to run is;

```
$ browserify function.js --standalone function > bundle.js
```

Based on this, the modified code is;

```
// add custom browserify options here
var customOpts = {
  entries: ['./function.js'],
  standalone: 'function',
};
```

Simply add one more property to `customOpts` for the --standalone parameter. The rest of the code remains the same.